# Simplifying $\frac{\cos(4a)-1}{\sin(a)-\sin(3a)}$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation, fractions

Got some questions from my niece who is studying for her exams. This one, I couldn't figure out:

> Simplify the following:
>   $$\frac{\cos(4a)-1}{\sin(a)-\sin(3a)}$$

I'm stuck at the $4a$ and $3a$... should I split $4a$ in $2a+2a$? Then what about the $3a$?

Everything that can help us get it right is much appreciated!

Comment: I would write $\sin$ and $\cos$ with the complex exponential and pray for some simplifications, but maybe there's a more clever way to follow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\cos4a-1}{\sin{a}-\sin{3a}}=\frac{-2\sin^22a}{-2\sin{a}\cos2a}=\frac{\sin2a}{\sin{a}}\cdot\frac{\sin2a}{\cos2a}$$
$$=\frac{2\sin{a}\cos{a}}{\sin{a}}\cdot\tan2a=2\cos{a}\tan2a.$$
I used the following.
$$1-\cos\alpha=2\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2};$$
$$\sin\alpha-\sin\beta=2\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2};$$
$$\sin2\alpha=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$$ and
$$\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}=\tan\alpha.$$

Comment: Ohhh right, Werner and  prosthaphaeresis, I always forget them

Comment: Thanks! Could you maybe provide a bit more steps so I see which formulas you've used? Still can't wrap my head around it...

Comment: @binoculars I added something. See now.

Comment: Got it! I didn't catch cos(4a)-1 could be seen as -(1-cos(4a)) at first. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!